# Reset Intellij / DataGrip 2020.1 font changes

Tags: intellij-idea, fonts, datagrip

Since I´ve installed DataGrip 2020.1 the font has changed to the new JetBrains Mono and it looks weird to me.

[image]

Which was the old font used by Jetbrains products?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was:

- `Menlo` or `Monospaced` on macOS.
- `Courier` or `Consolas` on Windows.
- `DeJavu` on Linux.

Try them if you don't like `JetBrains Mono`.

Comment: I reverted the font, but it still looked weird. In fact, I don't see much difference between JetBrains Mono, Menlo and Monospace. I found something else, though. I set the line spacing from 1.2 to 1.1 and that did the trick. IntelliJ now looks like what I'm used to.

Comment: @JeroenvanMontfort there are two places in the settings where you can change the font, One for the UI and one for the Editor. Just go to settings and search for "font" and you´ll find it

Comment: @MarianKlühspies thanks, but I changed the font in the right place, for the editor. I just wanted to add that changing the actual font face, for me personally, did not change much in the overall experience. The line height, however, made a big difference. I now have my IDE set to JetBrains Mono and line spacing 1.1 and it's fine now.